# can not make jQuery noConflict work

Tags: jquery

I have tried for days with no luck - I just can`t understand it
Have multiple scripts that use different jquerys but can not make them work together

```
<script src="/scripts/lavalamp/jquery-1.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
        var MyjQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="/scripts/lavalamp/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/scripts/lavalamp/jquery.lavalamp.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(function() {
        $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
            fx: "backout",
            speed: 700,
            click: function(event, menuItem) {
                return true; 
            }
        });
    });
})(MyjQ) 
</script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/scripts/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.2-min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/scripts/init.js" type="text/javascript">

<script src="/pages/cal/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
        var MyjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="/pages/cal/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/pages/cal/js/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){ 
    $(function() {
          var which_tab = $.cookie('which_tab') || 0;
          $("#tabs").tabs({
                   selected: which_tab,
                   select: function(e,ui){
                            $.cookie('which_tab', ui.index);
                   }
          });
     });
})(MyjQuery) 
</script>

</head>
```

Can you? How to accomplish this.. (I have read but just don`t understand how to use api.jquery examples)

update:
Even if after some effort it seems that it`s should work, errors will be thrown from jquery.cookie.js and other scripts. So var MyjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true); fixes (or not) var which_tab = $.cookie but what about ../jquery.cookie.js

Comment: Instead of using `noConflict` to use multiple versions of jQuery, I'd re-evaluate my plugins so that they can all use one single version of jQuery... the latest.  And secondly, I don't see `noConflict` anywhere in your code.

Comment: -1 `noConflict` does not appear in the code presented. Please make the question/code align.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using noconflict at all in your sample code. It is a bad idea to mix them, but if you must, use noconflic to rename each instance:

```
<script src="/pages/cal/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
$jq13 = jquery.noconflict(true);
$jq13.[code here to execute with JQuery 1.3]
</script>

<script src="/pages/cal/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
$jq14 = jquery.noconflict(true);
$jq14.[code here to execute with JQuery 1.4]
</script>
```